# jQuery's attr(...) in function parameter is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-attributes

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [webuiPopover](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover). It adds a popover to links. When the user hovers a link, the content of the popover is fetched through AJAX. This requires a certain `url` with appropriate parameters.

So this is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".qa-user-link").webuiPopover({
        placement:"auto",
        trigger:"hover",
        type:"async", 
        cache:false,
        url:"./qa-plugin/q2a-user-popover/qa-user-popover-details.php?handle="+$(this).attr("data-id")+"&incdir=%2Fhome%2Fpeatar5%2Fpublic_html%2Fbiophilie%2Fqa-include%2F",
        content:function(data) {return data;}
    });
});
```

As you can see I calculate the 'url' making use of jQuery's `attr(...)` function.
Unfortunately that little piece of code always returns 'undefined'.

If I use the same piece of code (`$(this).attr("data-id")`) in the `content` parameter (to give `function (data) {return $(this).attr("data-id");}` it works fine.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Well, what is `$(this)` _in this situation_? I suggest you use the browsers development console for this...

Comment: `$(this)` is supposed to be one of the possible elements having "qa-user-link" as class attribute. I thought that jQuery automatically looped through every one of these elements and that `$(this)` was referring to them... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well... "is supposed" does not really help here, does it? Don't guess, but look what it is!

Comment: yeah I'm lucky Paulpro's code worked, otherwise your suggestion would have uncovered it too, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the `document` inside the callback of `$(document).ready`. It works inside the `content` callback, because the plugin is [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the element to `content` when it calls it.

If you want to have a distinct url for each popover, you'll have to bind the popover plugin separately for each element:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".qa-user-link").each( function ( ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.webuiPopover({
            placement:"auto",
            trigger:"hover",
            type:"async", 
            cache:false,
            url:"./qa-plugin/q2a-user-popover/qa-user-popover-details.php?handle="+$this.attr("data-id")+"&incdir=%2Fhome%2Fpeatar5%2Fpublic_html%2Fbiophilie%2Fqa-include%2F",
            content:function(data) {return data;}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you so much! (i cannot upvote because i don't have the necessary reputation for it)